# Creating a dynamic library, is this the correct path?

Tags: libraries

I am trying to learn how to make static & dynamic libraries, and I am having a bit of a problem understanding my teacher regarding libraries. My idea to creating a dynamic library is this:

```
gcc -c main.c -o main.o
gcc -c -fPIC func.c -o func.o
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,-libfunc.so.1 -o libfunc.so.1.0.1 func.o
ldconfig -n .
ln -sf libfunc.so.1.0.1 libfunc.so
gcc main.o libfunc.so.1.0.1 -o prog1
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=.:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Now my teacher says the line before last must look like this:

```
gcc main.o -o prog1 -L. -lfunc
```

Can someone explain me the exact difference between those two?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`-l<name>` is only a shortcut saying "look for `lib<name>.so` or `lib<name>.a` in the configured library paths", and `-L.` just adds the current directory to said path.

Of course, `-l` is preferred when using real libraries, since it removes the need to know the full path of the library nor various OS details (like `.so` vs `.dylib` vs `.a` vs `.dll`), but there should be no difference when the executable is being output.

```
$ gcc -o out1 main.c libtest.so
$ gcc -o out2 main.c -L. -ltest
$ md5sum out*
b1b8f46bf6091377b202df90d6bd32cc  out1
b1b8f46bf6091377b202df90d6bd32cc  out2
```

See the `ld` manual page for a longer description of both `-l` and `-L`.